# import error in python

Tags: python, python-import

I have write down a code requires  one module name "fragbuilder". Every thing was working fine  until i have write down this code.

when I import module from command line its imported successfully but when I import same module from a script or  from a IDE its  showing error module not found :

and some of my previous scripts which were working fine before writing the new code but has stopped working now. :

example script given bellow:

```
$ python test.py 

import fragbuilder 
from fragbuilder  import peptide 
print "imported successfully"



Error: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new.py", line 3, in <module>
    import fragbuilder
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fragbuilder/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from peptide import Peptide
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fragbuilder/peptide.py", line 3, in <module>
    import openbabel
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openbabel.py", line 46, in <module>
    from new import instancemethod as new_instancemethod
  File "/home/zebrafish/Desktop/edited_ds/new/new.py", line 4, in <module>
    from fragbuilder import peptide
ImportError: cannot import name peptide
```

what should be the probable cause of this error: please suggest thanks

Comment: It looks like your file is called `new.py` instead of `test.py` (see second line of backtrace) and that somewhere in the `openbabel` module imported in the `fragbuilder` package, something expects a module called `new`. So your local `new.py` is shadowing the expected `new` module and the import fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely you have added `new.py` to `/home/zebrafish/Desktop/edited_ds/new/` which interfers with python builtin `new` module (should be located at `/usr/lib/python2.7/new.py`)

Recipe: rename `new.py` in your project to something else.

Comment: yes its true, after renaming the "new.py" everything is working smoothly thanks a lot.